# How can I add images to an HTML/CSS calendar without using a table?

Tags: html, css

I have literally just started learning, and I just want to add an image for each day. For example, for Sunday the 30th, I want to add an image of a sun, the temperature, and text saying it's mostly sunny.

Again, I am in no way a professional, so any advice would be appreciated. I have both the HTML and CSS below.

I want the border around each date with an image, temperature, and date of the month.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 18px Helvetica;
}

{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#Day {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 14.2857%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Month">
  <div id='Day'>
    <ul>
      <li>SUN</li>
      <li>MON</li>
      <li>TUE</li>
      <li>WED</li>
      <li>THUR</li>
      <li>FRI</li>
      <li>SAT</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>30</li>
      <li>31</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
      <li>21</li>
      <li>22</li>
      <li>23</li>
      <li>24</li>
      <li>25</li>
      <li>26</li>
      <li>27</li>
      <li>28</li>
      <li>29</li>
      <li>30</li>
      <li>31</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: "*I want to add an image of a sun, the temperature, and text saying it's mostly sunny.*" - and where is this information coming from?

Comment: What's wrong with a `table`? That's **exactly** what a calendar is!

Comment: If you don't want to use a table, at least use display grid and avoid the list, you may have a chance that screen readers will do something with it, Anyhow, you should use a table, so it can seen and read  as a calendar not a list of days then numbers unrelated. **aside** border with image, sounds a lot like `border-image`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this output??

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 18px Helvetica;
}
{border: 1px solid black;}


#Day {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.container img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
}
.centered-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 14.2857%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Month"> 
 <div id='Day' >
  <ul>
    <li>SUN</li>
    <li>MON</li>
    <li>TUE</li>
    <li>WED</li>
    <li>THUR</li>
    <li>FRI</li>
    <li>SAT</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
        
        <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">30</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">31</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">1</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">2</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">3</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">4</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">5</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">6</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">7</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">8</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">30</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/33-339321_sunny-clipart-august-weather-partly-cloudy-clip-art.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">1</div>
          <div class="centered-bottom">Mostly Cloudy</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>25</li>
    <li>26</li>
    <li>27</li>
    <li>28</li>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>30</li>
    <li>31</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
    html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 18px Helvetica;
}
{border: 1px solid black;}


#Day {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 

}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 14.2857%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
    border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forecast Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forecast.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Month"> 
    <div id='Day' >
  <ul>
    <li>SUN</li>
    <li>MON</li>
    <li>TUE</li>
    <li>WED</li>
    <li>THUR</li>
    <li>FRI</li>
    <li>SAT</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>30</li>
    <li>31</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>25</li>
    <li>26</li>
    <li>27</li>
    <li>28</li>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>30</li>
    <li>31</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

above is using your existing code with a boarder around days.